# Openshift secrets key naming constraint

Tags: openshift

1. Is there any constraint about the key of the open secrets? It seems that if I have "." inside the key like "hello.world", when adding to the environment variable, the value cannot be resolved
2. If I add a secret having the key "hello.world" and add to the deployments using the command "oc set env --from=secret/mysecret deployment.apps/myapp", the environment variable will be changed to "HELLO_WORLD" automatically. Is there any option to set without this conversion?

[secrets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqGZ6.png)

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a limitation on environment variable names (at least in the BASH shell), rather than a limitation on secret key names. See here below, for example, where in my terminal I can't set an environment variable called `hello.world`, but I can set one called `HELLO_WORLD` just fine:

```
sh-5.0$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
sh-5.0$ export hello.world=1
sh: export: `hello.world=1': not a valid identifier
sh-5.0$ export HELLO_WORLD=1
sh-5.0$ echo $HELLO_WORLD
1
sh-5.0$
```